# Where to put @Transactional? In interface specification or implementation?

Tags: java, spring, interface, transactions

What is considered the best practice in placing the `@Transactional` annotation? Should I annotate the interface method or the implementation?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Good question. I've always put it in the implementation. Perhaps because it is an implementation detail, rather than an abstraction.

You may want different implementations to have different transactional behaviours.

El Guapo noted that, in addition to that, there are more issues that can arise from putting on on the interface, related to the proxying strategy.

Comment: makes another very good point. Nice Comment!

Comment: Anyone know what the JTA spec says with regards to the annotation? Must providers check the supertype's method signature for the annotation? And more to the point, if one overrides an annotated method with an non-annotated version, how is that perceived by an annotation processor/reflection?

Answer (score 55):

It really all depends on your application architecture, in my opinion. It depends on how you are proxying your classes. If you have your app set to `proxy-target-class='true'` (in your application context, then your `@Transactional` information wont be picked up if you annotate the Interface.

Check out [The Spring Docs -- "Tips"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) for more information.

> Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Transactional annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies. The fact that Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces  means that if you are using class-based proxies (proxy-target-class="true") or the weaving-based aspect (mode="aspectj"), then the transaction settings are not recognized by the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy, which would be decidedly bad.

Comment: +1 for the tip. I'm editing your answer to add a quote

Comment: Is there a way to have `public class MyImplementation implements NonTransactionalInterface, TransactionalInterface { /* ... */ }` and then autowire only the interface which wasn't marked with `@Transactional` (`@Autowiring NonTransactionalInterface serviceImplementationWithoutUsingTransactions`) ? (Of course, in that example, both `MyImplementation` and `NonTransactionalInterface` are lacking `@Transactional`, while only `TransactionalInterface` is marked by that annotation.)

Answer (score 1):

While transactions management is implementation detail in many cases quite often it's an interface detail as well. For example, when defining interface of services of your application you might consider putting `@Transactional` into interface definition to specifically clarify what propagation strategy you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use interfaces on my system because so far I don't really see if it will be possible to implement anything over it. So I put annotations on the implementation and I believe Spring  would make everything correct to me.

I don't think that all classes must have interfaces. I see around lots of architectures with lots of patterns and they all love interfaces. But a question: if you put the Spring annotation into the interface and you, for some reason, you want another approach to the transaction of an implementation class done over this interface, you couldn't do that. Or am I wrong?

Cheers.